# How do you make text selectable on a jQuery draggable div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a div draggable using jQuery. However, there is some text in that box, and I would still like to be able to copy and paste the text, but when I make an item draggable well when I click on the box it starts to move the box?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

Use [the `cancel` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-cancel) when making the element draggable.

> Prevents dragging from starting on specified elements.

```
$('.selector').draggable({ cancel: '.text' });
```

Comment: This is a much better answer for the simple fact that it's shorter and uses the built in functionality.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this simple and useful solution.

Comment: could you provide more detail in html?

Answer (score 15):

It doesn't make sense to allow dragging AND selecting text on the same element. However, if you keep thinking it's necessary, two things come to my mind:

#### Solution 1:

You can add a "handler" that will be the only child receiving the mouse down/up events to drag the div. For instance:

```
<div id="draggable">
  <div class="handler"></div>
  <div class="text">This is a selectable text</div>
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript code:

```
var draggableDiv = $('#draggable');
draggableDiv.draggable({
  handle: $('.text', draggableDiv)
});
```

#### Solution 2:

You can disable the draggable thing when a user try to select text:

```
<div id="draggable">
  <div class="text">This is a text</div>
</div>
```

And in your JavaScript code:

```
var draggableDiv = $('#draggable').draggable();
$('.text', draggableDiv).mousedown(function(ev) {
  draggableDiv.draggable('disable');
}).mouseup(function(ev) {
  draggableDiv.draggable('enable');
});
```

When someone tries to select something in `.text`, the draggable process is disabled.

The first solution is the proper one.

Comment: The solution by @Lapa is much better

Comment: Agreed. I can't delete my answer though, I guess @SamFisher83 would have to uncheck my answer and check Lapa's one.

Comment: Simple use case for this would be to make a dialog (div) draggable but then to allow the user to select text inside an embedded div

Answer (score 0):

(As talked by the other 2 answers, but if you need an practical example, here it is (if I understood correctly): )

[jsfiddle: Draggable demo](https://jsfiddle.net/SelectNt/q3u2j7cz/)

The point is to:_

1. add an extra `child <span>` as an `dragHandler`, in the `(parent) <span>` that you want to drag.

```html
<span class="commentNt" id="commentDraggable_123">~//? was it not &quot;single bounded context&quot; in choreography?<br/>
  <span class="dragHandler">Drag</span></span>
```

2. for the `parent <span>`, use following code to register that `child <span>`  for dragging

   - (dragging will now only be triggered in `child <span>`'s region).

```js
$('#commentDraggable_123').draggable({ handle: '.dragHandler' });
```

3. now, only dragging the `child <span>`, the whole `parent <span>` will then be dragged along with.

---

As for:

- Q: Can I do this without introducing another `child <span>` inside the `parent <span>`?

  - ie: Can I just drag the "blank area", then the whole `parent <span>` is dragged;

    while I drag on the "text area", the text can be selected instead of being dragged?
- A: idk, I hope there is a way.