# jQuery UI draggable and text selection

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using jQuery 1.8.3 and jQuery UI 1.9.2.
My web application has got some draggable elements and I would like to allow the user to select some text in the contained elements.
I've seen there are some other questions on this topic.
Another path I am following is use the right-click of the mouse and use some text-selection plug-in I have found.
Still I can't make it work.

It seems that draggable/sortable elements don't allow text selection or can intercept mouse (clicks) events.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you wrap your text in a div tag then set the jquery .click function for that div to preventDefault (removing the dragging event) this way the div will only surround the text so when the user clicks that div, the draggable event is removed? Just a shot in the dark.

Comment: [this is](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15157335/7298124) the best answer with built-in functionality :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your approach is correct and that you can use right-click to copy the text from certain divs.

E.g. with:

```
<script src="http://cachedcommons.org/cache/zero-clipboard/1.0.7/javascripts/zero-clipboard-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div id="dragme" class="temp">Draggable Text</div>
```

as well as including jquery-ui, the following JavaScript should allow you to use left-click to drag and drop a div, and right-click to copy the text within the div:

```
$("#dragme").draggable();

$.event.special.rightclick = {
    bindType: "contextmenu",
    delegateType: "contextmenu"
};

ZeroClipboard.setMoviePath('http://zeroclipboard.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ZeroClipboard10.swf');
//Create a new clipboard client
var clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();

$(document).on("rightclick", ".ui-draggable", function() {

        //Grab the text from the parent row of the icon
        var txt = $(this).text();
        alert("Copying text: "+txt);
        clip.setText(txt);
        clip.glue(this);

        //Add a complete event to let the user know the text was copied
        clip.addEventListener('complete', function(client, text) {
            alert("Copied text to clipboard:\n" + text);
        });
        clip.hide();
        return false;
});
```

I have a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mccannf/4AaQa/9/) for this but I think the SWF copy with ZeroClipboard doesn't agree with jsfiddle.
But it should work in your development environment.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the draggable class from the parent element using on mouseenter event for the child element to select text. Then re-add the draggable class on the parent element using on mouseleave for the child element.